Foundation under brick corner is moving/detached
Context: I'm a relatively new homeowner living in a 1958 brich house in Canada (think winters). FWIW, my house is old, has very few water holes and the face where the corner broke off is where the wind and the sun comes from (i.e. east facing wall). I saw small hairline cracks in my foundation last year and tried to push cement (Quikrete) in them, but I think I have attracted more trouble by doing so.
Issue (pictures linked): My foundation seems weak near the corner of my house (like some parts chip easily) and the entire corner even came off! Now, I have googled it and it seems to be a phenomenon called corner pop? I have many horizontal hairline cracks directly under the brick (very very small).
Images:


Questions:

Is this a big problem? (If it truly is corner pop, then from what I read, no, but just making sure I hear a bunch of people over the internet confirm or deny this haha!)
Can I repair this myself or should I contact a pro? If so, what should I use? (Concrete, cement? Which kind of cement/concrete?) I am not very handy when it comes to home repairs, but I try to learn.
How do I prevent further damage?

If you have any more advice, or need more info, please let me know, I would be grateful to be taught more!
Thank you for your feedback on this!

Use masking tape and put it on the brick so not to smear all over it.
Use concrete primer on that corner before applying concrete to make it stick.
Use QUIKRETE® Re-Cap® Concrete Resurfacer designed for making thin layer repairs.
